# rxjava arrange of output not unique

Tags: android, rx-java2

why output of these codes are different:

```
Observable.fromArray("Red", "Orange", "Blue")
            .doOnNext(color ->{
                Log.i(TAG, "Color "+  color + " pushed through on $ " +Thread.currentThread());})
            .map(String::length)
            .subscribe(length ->
                    Log.i(TAG, "Length $" + length + " being recieved on $" + Thread.currentThread()));
```

output:

```
Color Red pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Length $3 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
Color Orange pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Length $6 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
Color Blue pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Length $4 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
```

and

```
Observable.fromArray("Red", "Orange", "Blue")
                .doOnNext(color ->{
                    Log.i(TAG, "Color "+  color + " pushed through on $ " +Thread.currentThread());})
                .map(String::length)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(length ->
                        Log.i(TAG, "Length $" + length + " being recieved on $" + Thread.currentThread()));
```

output:

```
Color Red pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Color Orange pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Color Blue pushed through on $ Thread[main,5,main]
Length $3 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
Length $6 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
Length $4 being recieved on $Thread[main,5,main]
```

why Arrange of output are different?
each Scheduler that i use in observeon method but output is differnt
when trigger doonnext and subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doOnNext is being done on the current thread, the subscribe is being done on the the Schedulers.computation thread.  So the order they get done on may be random, due to multithreading race conditions.  The subscribeOn only applies to the object its directly called on.

Comment: why in first code, output arrange is: onnext, subscribe,onnext, subscribe,onnext, subscribe, but in seccond is: onnext,onnext,onnext,subscribe,subscribe,subscribe

Comment: Because in that case, everything is done on one thread, so its done in that order.  In the other case, they happen on 2 threads so any order may be possible (although some are more likely than others).  It may be the case that it will always do the doOnNext first in that case, but that's a deep implementation detail of rxJava and I wouldn't rely on it.  But a good rule of thumb is that if you have 2 threads, assume that they can execute anything in any order, unless you're synchronizing things carefully.